# Making new string after taking value of different columns of a dataframe and make new dataframe with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have below raw data as sample (In practical millions of data are there):

```
msisdn,recharge,voice,data,sms
88018318118,4,3,2,1
88018658030,40,30,20,10
```

I want to make new string taking values from recharge, voice, data and sms as below and modified dataframe would be below:

```
number, text
88018318108,you have recharged 4taka voice3taka data 2mb and sms 1
88018558530,you have recharged 40taka voice30taka data 20mb and sms 10
```

I can only do below but I think it is not practical work with millons of data. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

df=pd.read_csv('sbk1.txt', delimiter=',')
print(df)

filename=open('out.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout=filename

for row in df.iterrows():
    num=row[1].msisdn
    rec=row[1].recharge
    voi=row[1].voice
    dat=row[1].data
    sms=row[1].sms
    print('{},you have recharged {}taka voice{}taka data {}mb and sms {}'.format(num,rec,voi,dat,sms))
```

Comment: Try this out: `'You are combining ' + df['recharge'].astype(str) + ' and ' + df['voice'].astype(str) + '!'`

Comment: @RaymondKwok thanks but how to make new DataFrame from the output?

Comment: `df['combined']='You are combining ' + df['recharge'].astype(str) + ' and ' + df['voice'].astype(str) + '!'` with this you create a new column

Comment: Then you can drop irrelevant columns